# .style.display = "block" don't work any idea how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html

hi happy new year for all I have this problem with .style it shows this error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at HTMLImageElement.show (Slideshowmodal.js:15)

do you have any idea what I am messing up ?

```js
initmodal();

function initmodal()
  {
  modalclick = document.getElementsByClassName('Slideshowimg');

  for (i = 0; i < modalclick.length; i++) 
    {
    modalclick[i].onclick = function show()
      {
      Modalarts = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("modalria");

      for (j = 0; j < this.parentNode.children.length; j++)
        {
        this.Modalarts[j].style.display = "block";
        if (this.parentNode.children[j] == this)
          {
          index = j;
          }
        }
      this.Modalarts[index].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  };
```

```html
<div id="myModalriaArt" class="modalria">
  <span class="closer cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>

  <div class="modal-content-ria">

    <img class="Slideshowimgmodal" src="./imgs/Riaarts/1/Main1.jpg" 
         style="width:100%" alt="You left a big holedasdasda 30x40">

    <img class="Slideshowimgmodal" src="./imgs/Riaarts/1/RA1Z2.jpg"
         style="width:100%" alt="You left a big hole 30x40">
<!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't display the error you mention. So perhaps you have a typo in the code on your computer?

Comment: there is zero elements with className == "Slideshowimg".

Comment: Are you sure there are equal elements of `Modalarts` as there are children in `parentNode.children`? I think that is why `this.Modalarts[j]` fails,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
initmodal();
function initmodal() {
    modalclick = document.getElementsByClassName('Slideshowimg');
    for (i = 0; i < modalclick.length; i++) {
        modalclick[i].onclick = function show() {
            Modalarts = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("modalria");
            for (j = 0; j < this.parentNode.children.length; j++)   {
                this.Modalarts[j].style.display = "block";
                if (this.parentNode.children[j] == this) {
                    index = j;
                }
            }
            this.Modalarts[index].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
};

const cross = document.getElementById('cross')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById("myModalriaArt").style.display= "none";
    },false);
```

```html
<div id="myModalriaArt" class="modalria">
    <span id="cross" class="closer cursor">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content-ria">
          <img class="Slideshowimgmodal" src="./imgs/Riaarts/1/Main1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="You left a big holedasdasda 30x40">
           <img class="Slideshowimgmodal" src="./imgs/Riaarts/1/RA1Z2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="You left a big hole 30x40">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modalarts is defined as a local variable, so no need for "this" in front.